# Provided Services / Budgeted Services

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I posted a similar post yesterday but I don't think I articulated what I am trying to accomplish well.

I need calculate (1) the total amount of each WAIVER_SERVICE that was budgeted, (2) the total amount for each wavier service that was provided and (3) the % Budget Used. Grouped by WAIVER_SERVICES and 
Month/Year

```
CLT_NBR  WAIVER_SERVICES Month/Year Amount_Services_Provided  Amount_Budgeted  %_Budget_Used     
10178        2              1 2013          1000                 1100            90%           
10178        2              2 2013          950                  1000            95%     
10178        2              3 2013          759                   650            115%    
10178        4             11 2012          600                   1000            60%
10178        4             9 2013           100                   100            100%
```

If a client was budgeted a service and did not receive it for a month a 0 value is needed and I need to display 0's for months with no data.

Below are 3 temp tables which are examples of the original 3 tables used for the two programs. The tables are B2H_DSP, B2H_SummaryForms and B2H_RATE . Note the **B2H_Rate table** is a reference table which pulls the cost of the wavier_services.

**B2H_DSP TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE B2H_DSP (
  BGT_NBR    int,
  CLT_NBR    int,
  WAIVER_SERVICES    int,
  WAIVER_PROGRAM  int, 
  START_DT date,
  END_DT date, 
  BILLABLE_UNITS_OF_SERVICE int, 
  UNITS_PER_MONTH   int, 
  RATE_PER_UNIT_OF_SERVICE int, 
  PROJECTED_COST_PER_MONTH int, 
  NUMBER_OF_MONTHS_OF_SERVICES int,     
  PROJECTED_COST_PER_12_MONTHS int
); 

INSERT INTO B2H_DSP  VALUES 
(1,     10178,   9, 2,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  16, 12.7,   203.2,  12, 2633.47),
(1,     10178,  10, 2,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(1,     10178,  11, 2,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(1,     10178,  5,  2,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  28, 12.64,  353.92, 12, 4586.8),
(1,     10178,  2,  2,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  8,  13.23,  105.84, 12, 1371.69),
(1,     10178,  3,  2,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    5,  28, 13.23,  370.44, 12, 4800.9),
(1,     10178,  8,  2,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    6,  16, 13.23,  211.68, 12, 2743.37),
(1,     10178,  1,  1,  '7/21/2011',    '7/21/2012',    1,  1,  2040,   2040,   12, 24480),
(406,   10178,  1,  1,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    1,  1,  2040,   2040,   12, 24480),
(406,   10178,  2,  2,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    5,  8,  13.23,  105.84, 12, 1371.69),
(406,   10178,  3,  2,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    5,  28, 13.23,  370.44, 12, 4800.9),
(406,   10178,  5,  2,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    5,  20, 19.45,  389,    12, 5041.44),
(406,   10178,  8,  2,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    6,  16, 13.23,  211.68, 12, 2743.37),
(406,   10178,  9,  2,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    5,  16, 19.55,  312.8,  12, 4053.89),
(406,   10178,  10, 2,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    5,  8,  19.55,  156.4,  12, 2026.94),
(406,   10178,  11, 2,  '7/21/2012',    '7/21/2013',    5,  8,  19.55,  156.4,  12, 2026.94),
(933,   10178,  1,  1,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    1,  1,  2040,   2040,   12, 24480),
(933,   10178,  2,  2,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    5,  8,  13.23,  105.84, 12, 1371.69),
(933,   10178,  5,  2,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    5,  16, 19.45,  311.2,  12, 4033.15),
(933,   10178,  10, 2,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(933,   10178,  11, 2,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(933,   10178,  3,  2,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    5,  18, 13.23,  238.14, 12, 3086.29),
(933,   10178,  8,  2,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    3,  3,  236.7,  710.1,  12, 9202.9),
(933,   10178,  9,  2,  '7/21/2013',    '7/21/2014',    5,  18, 19.55,  351.9,  12, 4560.62),
(480,   12014,  1,  1,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    1,  1,  2040,   2040,   12, 24480),
(480,   12014,  1,  1,  '9/21/2011',    '10/21/2011',   1,  1,  2038,   2038,   1,  2038),
(480,   12014,  2,  2,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    5,  8,  8.6,    68.8,   12, 891.65),
(480,   12014,  3,  2,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    5,  8,  13.23,  105.84, 12, 1371.69),
(480,   12014,  5,  2,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    5,  8,  19.45,  155.6,  12, 2016.58),
(480,   12014,  8,  2,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    3,  2,  236.7,  473.4,  12, 6135.26),
(480,   12014,  9,  2,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(480,   12014,  10, 2,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(480,   12014,  11, 2,  '9/21/2011',    '9/21/2012',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(481,   12014,  1,  1,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    1,  1,  2040,   2040,   12, 24480),
(481,   12014,  2,  2,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    5,  8,  8.6,    68.8,   12, 891.65),
(481,   12014,  3,  2,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    5,  8,  13.23,  105.84, 12, 1371.69),
(481,   12014,  5,  2,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    5,  8,  19.45,  155.6,  12, 2016.58),
(481,   12014,  8,  2,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    3,  2,  236.7,  473.4,  12, 6135.26),
(481,   12014,  9,  2,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(481,   12014,  10, 2,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47),
(481,   12014,  11, 2,  '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2013',    5,  4,  19.55,  78.2,   12, 1013.47)
```

**B2H_SummaryForms TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE B2H_SummaryForms (
  CLT_NBR    int,
  DOSStart date,
  DOSEnd date,
  BillableUnits  int,
  RateCode int    
); 
INSERT INTO B2H_SummaryForms  VALUES 
(12014, '3/2/2012',     '3/2/2012',    10,  1312),
(12014, '3/30/2012',    '3/30/2012',   4,   1312),
(10178, '4/19/2012',    '4/19/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '5/9/2012',     '5/9/2012',     0,  1300),
(12014, '5/21/2012',    '5/21/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '6/1/2012',      '6/1/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '5/10/2012',    '5/10/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '6/19/2012',    '6/19/2012',    2,  1319),
(10178, '6/26/2012',    '6/26/2012',    2,  1312),
(12014, '7/27/2012',    '7/27/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '8/8/2012',      '8/8/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '7/13/2012',    '7/13/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '7/1/2012',      '7/1/2012',    8,  1312),
(10178, '7/2/2012',      '7/2/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '5/8/2012',      '5/8/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '5/10/2012',    '5/10/2012',    4,  1312),
(10178, '5/8/2012',      '5/8/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '4/2/2012',      '4/2/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '3/8/2012',      '3/8/2012',    1,  1312),
(10178, '5/10/2012',    '5/10/2012',    14, 1319),
(12014, '4/10/2012',    '4/10/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '2/29/2012',    '2/29/2012',    2,  1312),
(12014, '3/5/2012',      '3/5/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '2/7/2012',      '2/7/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '2/15/2012',    '2/15/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '2/29/2012',    '2/29/2012',    4,  1312),
(10178, '3/8/2012',      '3/8/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '5/10/2012',    '5/10/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '3/2/2012',      '3/2/2012',    10, 1312),
(10178, '3/15/2012',    '3/15/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014,'3/30/2012',     '3/30/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '4/4/2012',      '4/4/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '4/5/2012',      '4/5/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '4/19/2012',    '4/19/2012',    10, 1319),
(10178, '4/10/2012',    '4/10/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '5/17/2012',    '5/17/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '6/6/2012',      '6/6/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '6/19/2012',    '6/19/2012',    2,  1312),
(12014, '6/19/2012',    '6/19/2012',    2,  1319),
(10178, '7/23/2012',    '7/23/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '8/20/2012',    '8/20/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '8/25/2012',    '8/25/2012',    28, 1309),
(10178, '9/5/2012',      '9/5/2012',    0,  1300),
(10178, '8/25/2012',    '8/25/2012',    55, 1309),
(12014, '9/17/2012',    '9/17/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '9/14/2012',    '9/14/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '9/1/2012',      '9/1/2012',    1,  1318),
(12014, '8/31/2012',    '8/31/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '8/1/2012',      '8/1/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '5/10/2012',    '5/10/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '6/19/2012',    '6/19/2012',    2,  1312),
(12014, '6/19/2012',    '6/20/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '5/10/2012',    '5/10/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '6/11/2012',    '6/11/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '4/4/2012',      '4/4/2012',    2,  1312),
(12014, '2/22/2012',    '2/22/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '3/13/2012',    '3/13/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '3/20/2012',    '3/20/2012',    1,  1312),
(12014, '2/7/2012',      '2/7/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '9/15/2012',    '9/15/2012',    1,  1318),
(12014, '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2012',    4,  1312),
(10178, '9/13/2012',    '9/13/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '9/22/2012',    '9/22/2012',    1,  1318),
(10178, '1/8/2013',      '1/8/2013',    1,  1300),
(12014, '9/21/2012',    '9/21/2012',    4,  1312),
(12014, '10/5/2012',    '10/5/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '10/8/2012',    '10/8/2012',    1,  1300),
(10178, '10/10/2012',   '10/10/2012',   1,  1300),
(10178, '10/2/2012',    '10/2/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '10/6/2012',    '10/6/2012',    16, 1308),
(10178, '10/19/2012',   '10/19/2012',   1,  1318),
(10178, '10/20/2012',   '10/20/2012',   16, 1319),
(10178, '10/20/2012',   '10/20/2012',   16, 1319),
(10178, '10/19/2012',   '10/19/2012',   1,  1318),
(10178, '11/5/2012',    '11/5/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '11/6/2012',    '11/6/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '9/28/2012',    '9/28/2012',    16, 1308),
(12014, '10/27/2012',   '10/27/2012',   16, 1308),
(12014, '11/9/2012',    '11/9/2012',    1,  1300),
(12014, '10/15/2012',   '10/15/2012',   4,  1312),
(12014, '10/6/2012',    '10/6/2012',    16, 1308),
(12014, '9/28/2012',    '9/28/2012',    16, 1308),
(12014, '10/27/2012',   '10/27/2012',   16, 1308),
(12014, '11/10/2012',   '11/10/2012',   16, 1308),
(10178, '11/12/2012',   '11/12/2012',   1,  1300),
(12014, '11/10/2012',   '11/10/2012',   16, 1308),
(12014, '11/17/2012',   '11/17/2012',   12, 1308),
(12014, '10/15/2012',   '10/15/2012',   4,  1312),
(12014, '11/16/2012',   '11/16/2012',   4,  1312),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   16, 1308),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   1,  1307),
(12014, '11/17/2012',   '11/17/2012',   12, 1308),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   16, 1308),
(12014, '12/1/2012',    '12/1/2012',    16, 1308),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   1,  1307),
(10178, '12/3/2012',    '12/3/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   16, 1308),
(12014, '12/1/2012',    '12/1/2012',    16, 1308),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   1,  1307),
(12014, '12/17/2012',   '12/17/2012',   0,  1300),
(10178, '12/10/2012',   '12/10/2012',   1,  1300),
(10178, '12/10/2012',   '12/19/2012',   1,  1300),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   1,  1307),
(12014, '12/21/2012',   '12/21/2012',   1,  1300),
(12014, '12/22/2012',   '12/22/2012',   16, 1308),
(12014, '11/24/2012',   '11/24/2012',   1,  1307),
(12014, '1/5/2013',      '1/5/2013',    1,  1318),
(10178, '1/8/2013',      '1/8/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '1/7/2013',      '1/7/2013',    0,  1300),
(10178, '1/7/2013',      '1/7/2013',    0,  1300),
(10178, '5/8/2012',      '5/8/2012',    0,  1300),
(12014, '1/23/2013',    '1/23/2013', 0, 1300),
(12014, '1/25/2013',    '1/25/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '2/4/2013',      '2/4/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '2/2/2013',      '2/2/2013',    1,  1318),
(12014,'2/11/2013',     '2/11/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '2/19/2013',    '2/19/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '2/19/2013',    '2/19/2013',    1,  1300),
(12014,'2/23/2013',     '2/23/2013',    8,  1308),
(10178, '3/4/2013',      '3/4/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '3/9/2013',      '3/9/2013',    1,  1318),
(12014, '3/9/2013',      '3/9/2013',    1,  1318),
(12014, '3/7/2013',      '3/7/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '3/15/2013',    '3/15/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '3/12/2013',    '3/12/2013',    8,  1306),
(10178, '3/13/2013',    '3/13/2013',    3,  1312),
(10178, '3/12/2013',    '3/12/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '3/21/2013',    '3/21/2013',    2,  1308),
(10178, '3/21/2013',    '3/21/2013',    4,  1319),
(10178, '3/20/2013',    '3/20/2013',    2,  1312),
(10178, '3/23/2013',    '3/23/2013',    1,  1318),
(12014, '4/2/2013',      '4/2/2013',    0,  1300),
(10178, '4/2/2013',      '4/2/2013', 0, 1300),
(12014, '4/6/2013',      '4/6/2013',    1,  1318),
(10178, '4/5/2013',      '4/5/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '4/10/2013',    '4/10/2013',    4,  1312),
(10178, '4/11/2013',    '4/11/2013',    6,  1308),
(12014, '4/22/2013',    '4/22/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '5/2/2013',      '5/2/2013',    0,  1300),
(10178, '5/2/2013',      '5/2/2013',    6,  1319),
(10178, '5/4/2013',      '5/4/2013',    1,  1318),
(10178, '5/16/2013',    '5/16/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '5/14/2013',    '5/14/2013',    6,  1312),
(12014, '5/17/2013',    '5/17/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '5/20/2013',    '5/20/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '6/6/2013',      '6/6/2013',    0,  1300),
(10178, '6/10/2013',    '6/10/2013',    1,  1300),
(10178, '6/1/2013',      '6/1/2013',    1,  1318),
(12014, '6/7/2013',      '6/7/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '6/17/2013',    '6/17/2013',    1,  1300),
(12014, '6/19/2013',    '6/19/2013',    4,  1308),
(12014, '6/29/2013',    '6/29/2013',    1,  1318),
(12014, '6/29/2013',    '6/29/2013',    8,  1308),
(10178, '7/10/2013',    '7/10/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '7/11/2013',    '7/11/2013',    0,  1300),
(12014, '7/3/2013',      '7/3/2013',    4,  1308),
(12014, '7/13/2013',    '7/13/2013',    1,  1318),
(10178, '7/24/2013',    '7/24/2013',    1,  1300)
```

**B2H_RATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE B2H_RATE (
  RATE_CODE  int,
  WAIVER_SERVICES date,
  RATE_AMOUNT    date,
  BILLABLE_UNIT  int
);

(1300,  1,  2040,   1),
(1301,  1,  2038,   1),
(1302,  1,  1020,   2),
(1303,  1,  1020,   2),
(1304,  1,  2040,   1),
(1305,  1,  2040,   1),
(1306,  2,  13.23,  5),
(1307,  2,  8.6,    5),,
(1308,  3,  13.23,  5),
(1309,  3,  8.6,    5),
(1310,  4,  77, 4),
(1311,  4,  40.85,  4),
(1312,  5,  19.45,  5),
(1313,  5,  12.64,  5),
(1314,  6,  55.68,  4),
(1315,  6,  30.19,  4),
(1316,  7,  70, 4),
(1317,  8,  13.23,  6),
(1318,  8,  236.7,  3),
(1319,  9,  19.55,  5),
(1320,  9,  12.7,   5),
(1321,  10, 19.55,  5),
(1322,  11, 19.55,  5),
(1323,  12, 17.59,  6),
(1324,  12, 304.5,  3),
(1327,  1,  2040,   1),
(1328,  1,  2038,   1),
(1329,  1,  1020,   2),
(1330,  1,  1020,   2)
(1331,  1,  2040,   1),
(1332,  1,  2040,   1),
(1333,  2,  13.23,  5),
(1334,  2,  8.6,    5),
(1335,  3,  13.23,  5),
(1336,  3,  8.6,    5),
(1337,  4,  77, 4),
(1338,  4,  40.85,  4),
(1339,  5,  19.45,  5),
(1340,  5,  12.64,  5),
(1341,  6,  55.68,  4)
(1342,  6,  30.19,  4),
(1343,  7,  70, 4),
(1344,  8,  13.23,  6),
(1345,  8,  236.7,  3),
(1346,  9,  19.55,  5),
(1347,  9,  12.7,   5),
(1348,  10, 19.55,  5),
(1349,  11, 19.55,  5),
(1350,  12, 17.59,  6),
(1351,  12, 304.5,  3),
(1354,  1,  2040,   1),
(1355,  1,  2038,   1),
(1356,  1,  1020,   2),
(1357,  1,  1020,   2),
(1358,  1,  2040,   1),
(1359,  1,  2040,   1),
(1360,  2,  13.23,  5),
(1361,  2,  8.6,    5),
(1362,  3,  13.23,  5),
(1363,  3,  8.6,    5),
(1364,  4,  77, 4),
(1365,  4,  40.85,  4),
(1366,  5,  19.45,  5),
(1367,  5,  12.64,  5),
(1368,  6,  55.68,  4),
(1369,  6,  30.19,  4),
(1370,  7,  70, 4),
(1371,  8,  17.3,   6),
(1372,  8,  309.42, 3),
(1373,  9,  19.55,  5),
(1374,  9,  12.7,   5),
(1375,  10, 19.55,  5),
(1376,  11, 19.55,  5),
(1377,  12, 23.94,  6),
(1378,  12, 414.48, 3)
```

This is what I have so far. I've been trying but I can't figure out how to get the output above.

**Budgeted**

```
SELECT 
  ChildID,
  WAIVER_SERVICES,
  START_DT,
  END_DT,
  RATE_PER_UNIT_OF_SERVICE,
  PROJECTED_COST_PER_MONTH
FROM [ECMS_BACKUP].[dbo].[B2H_DSP]
where WAIVER_PROGRAM=2
```

The budgets can be renewed once a year So the Start_Dt and End_dt are always a year long. This makes it tricky to break down the budget amount by month.

**Services Provided**

```
select 
  a.CLT_NBR,
  b.WAIVER_SERVICES,
  month(a.DOSStart) as Month, 
  YEAR(a.DOSStart) as Year,
  sum(b.RATE_AMOUNT)as total
from 
    [ECMS_BACKUP].[dbo].[B2H_SummaryForms]a
left JOIN ECMS_BACKUP.dbo.B2H_RATE b ON a.RateCode=b.RATE_CODE
where DOSStart>='2013-01-01' AND DOSStart<'2013-06-30' /*I selected a 6th month time frame for   services provided */
group by ChildID, month(a.DOSStart), YEAR(a.DOSStart),WAIVER_SERVICES
order by childid,  month(a.DOSStart), YEAR(a.DOSStart),WAIVER_SERVICES
```

Comment: `FROM [ECMS_BACKUP].[dbo].[B2H_DSP]
and WAIVER_PROGRAM=2` is not legal SQL

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?  I see date type so 2008 or 2012

Comment: @hogan MS SQL server 2008

Comment: @hogan I changed the and to where